# Storing & retrieving complex data to MySQL BLOB to retrieve data in same state prior to encode & DB insertion using PHP

Tags: php, mysql, excel, csv, encoding

I am building a function that is inserting complex data into a MySQL table to be used as a queue for a CSV file creation. Without going into explicit details, what I want is simply to convert an array into serialized format using json_encode, insert it to a MySQL table with a prepared statement, and then retrieve that data, json_decode, and have the original data in the exact same form it was prior to insertion.

The code as it stands looks something like this:

```
// Array data previously created

foreach ( $array as $key => $element ) {

  $array[$key] = htmlspecialchars($element,ENT_QUOTES);

}

$this->db->query("UPDATE `table` SET `blob_field` = '".$this->db->escape($array)."' WHERE `id` = '".(int)$id."'");
```

Then I retrieve the data using:

```
$decoded_array = $this->db->query("SELECT `blob_field` FROM `table` WHERE `id` = '".(int)$id."'")->row['blob_field'];

$decoded_array = json_decode($decoded_array);
$decoded_array = array_map('htmlspecialchars_decode',$decoded_array);

// Add to CSV using fputcsv standard process
```

The resulting CSV is about 99.9% perfect. But when opened in Excel about 0.1% of the rows have columns that are jumping where they should not. Furthermore, every instance of \r\n appears to be getting replaced with the Windows newline character.

My question is... what am I doing wrong? Why are the newline characters being replaced with the Windows equivalent, and why does the CSV look messed up when opened in Excel?

Comment: Can you attach a sample of the raw data (before inserting into your db) in a file to your post?

Comment: Not without compromising the security of the application. However, what I can tell you is that the data types of the array elements are widely varied, from integer values to multidimensional arrays, some of which contain raw HTML markup, which is where all of the unexpected breaks occur. All is UTF-8, including the MySQL table itself. Also a caveat, we are limited in both field separator and quote character for the CSV output to: comma, semicolon / none, single quote, and double quote respectively.

Comment: Why use htmlspecialchars?

Comment: `\r\n` is Windows; `\n` is Unix.  Which are you writing?  Why not write what the recipient is expecting.

Comment: `escape($array)`?  Don't you mean `json_encode($array, JSON_UNESCAPED_UNICODE);`?